# Make this report in one SQL in C#

Tags: sql, ms-access

**EDIT: the database is Access 2007**

Hi, I'm new here and I need some help:

I have three tables:

1. **technicians** (Id, tech_name, is_active)
2. **type_services** (Id, serv_name, is_active)
3. **services** (Id, date_time, prod_name, quantity, serv_type, tech_name, is_active)

I have to make a report that contain:

1. Number of services per tech (SUM(quantity))
2. Number of type of services per tech
3. Total per each services
4. Total of services

Example:

```
TECH_NAME TYPE_SERV1 TYPE_SERV2 TYPE_SERV3 TYPE_SERV4 TYPE_SERV5 TYPE_SERV6 TOTAL

NAME1     2          0          3          7          15         52         79
NAME2     0          0          1          6          18         45         70
NAME3     0          0          2          3          13         38         56
NAME4     1          1          0          3          11         21         37

TOTAL     3          1          6          19         57         156        242
```

All using a date interval

**NOTE: In the services table I use the string name of serv_type and tech_name directly, so I don't use the number id**

This is the **NEW** sql, that it's works but if it's possible to make all this in a SQL sentence with no C# extra code, because not always there are one type services on services

> SELECT
>   COUNT(Srvs.serv_type) AS numReg,
>   SUM(Srvs.quantity) AS tot,
>   Techs.tech_name AS tchs,
>   Srvs.serv_type AS srv 
>   FROM 
>   technicians AS Techs, 
>   type_services AS TySrv,
>   services AS Srvs 
>   WHERE 
>   (Techs.is_active = true AND
>   TySrv.is_active = true AND
>   Srvs.is_active = true) AND
>   (Srvs.date_time BETWEEN #2010/06/01 00:00:00# AND #2010/08/30 23:59:59# 
>   AND Srvs.tech_name = Techs.tech_name)
>   AND Srvs.serv_type = TySrv.serv_name
>   GROUP BY Srvs.serv_type, Techs.tech_name
>   ORDER BY Techs.tech_name ASC

Before this SQL I had three SQL to make this report xD, so I need that be more simple with one SQL

Thanks and I hope you know what I'm trying to say

Comment: SQL in C#?  I'm confused.  Where's the C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access, I think you want something like this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(services.quantity) AS SumOfquantity
SELECT services.tech_name, 
       Sum(services.quantity) AS [Total Of Quantity], 
       Count(services.serv_type) AS [Count of Services]
FROM (services 
INNER JOIN technicians ON services.tech_name = technicians.tech_name) 
INNER JOIN type_services ON services.serv_type = type_services.serv_name
WHERE services.is_active=True 
    AND technicians.is_active=True
    AND type_services.is_active=True 
    AND services.date_time Between #6/1/2010# And #8/30/2010 23:59:59#
GROUP BY services.tech_name
PIVOT services.serv_type
```

if you wish to vary the dates, you can use a parameter.

Comment: Yeah this works, but somes values are NULL so I change this: > TRANSFORM Sum(services.quantity) AS SumOfquantity
for this: > TRANSFORM IIF(Sum(services.quantity) IS NULL, 0,Sum(services.quantity)) AS SumOfquantity and it's works, thanks so much

Comment: You can use Nz: Nz(Sum([Quantity]),0) - you can use anything instead of 0, "N/A" for example, which may be more appropriate.

Comment: I use Nz() function but show me an error message: "The NZ function is not defined in the expression" I google it and I think that function is for access 2003, now I use: IIF(ISNULL(Sum(services.quantity)), 0,Sum(services.quantity)) and it works fine, thanks again for you time

Comment: Hi again Remou, last question xD how do I: ORDER BY [Total Of Quantity] DESC, I tested but seems to be complicated for me